# Прозрачный TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть форма с установленной фоновой картинкой. Поверх у меня лежит `TextBox1`. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы фон `TextBox` исчез, т.е. просвечивал `BackgroundImage` формы.

Пробовал делать так:

```
SetStyle(System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor | System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.UserPaint | System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
textbox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Но генерирует исключение типа:

> Control does not support transparent background colors.

Хотелось добиться такого результата:

[image: Результат должен быть примерно таким]

Answer (score 0):

```
private ZBobb.AlphaBlendTextBox alphaBlendTextBox1; 
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    alphaBlendTextBox1 = new ZBobb.AlphaBlendTextBox();
    alphaBlendTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(32, 16);
    this.alphaBlendTextBox1.Text = "Hello";
    alphaBlendTextBox1.BackAlpha = 0; // Totally transparent
    this.Controls.Add(this.alphaBlendTextBox1);
}
```

Взято [отсюда](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4390/AlphaBlendTextBox-A-transparent-translucent-textbo)

---

Я бы не рекомендовал вам проводить такие махинации, так как для этого всё таки существует `WPF`. А на `WinForms` стоит писать, когда не так важна графическая часть приложения (имхо)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я не знал что такое WPF, теперь буду использовать ее

Comment: Товарищ, Вы уверены, что это будет работать? Сие дело было создано для `.NET 1.1`, в то время как сейчас актуальная версия `.NET 4.7+`. Мне кажется, я пробовал использовать данный контрол, да он оказался несовместим с новыми версиями фреймворка

Comment: Я вообще против использование такого подхода. В рамках моего проекта я бы его не использовал. Я не знаю цели и намерения пользователя, для чего ему это и в этом роде. И я по моему в конце это описал.

Comment: Нет-нет, Ваше мнение понятно (я с ним даже солидарен: важен внешний вид - используй WPF), я про то, проверяли ли Вы работоспособность своего ответа?